# Bundle resources not being updated on app.

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I updated the splash screen on my iOS application; but, the app continues to launch with the previous splash screen. When I launch the application in the simulator, it works fine.

I have a similar problem with other images as well. If I don't change the file name, sometimes the images are not being updated.

Any ideas as to why this happens and what i can do to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

First uninstall the old app and then install the new build app.

Comment: Also, Clean & Rebuild in xCode is also needed.

Comment: what are the names of your Default screens and what kind of physical device are you really testing with?